# Where should my javascript live in my Rails 4 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to work out where I should put the following snippets of code in my Rails 4 app in order for them to be included in the asset pipeline.

The following is used on my form:

```
<input id="tag" type="text" name="tags" value="">

<p>
<a class="tag">aaa</a><br/>
<a class="tag">bbb</a><br/>
<a class="tag">ccc</a><br/>
<a class="tag">ddd</a><br/>
<a class="tag">eee</a>
</p>
```

Where should the following code be placed so that is is triggered by the above html?:

```
$('a.tag').live('click', function(e){
$('#tag').val(this.innerHTML);
return false; 
});
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/Kaf3V/4/

UPDATE:
The JS, is being loaded correctly, but simply doesn't work in Rails 4(?)

Thanks

Comment: I maybe be off topic but, you really need to switch to [link](http://api.jquery.com/on/)`.on()` at some point. The syntax is `$('#aParentElement').on('click', '#targetElement', function(e){`. Just a thought. EDIT, [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/)live have been removed from the new versions of jquery, so any update the jquery script would brake the script.

Comment: ^^ Added to my To Do list

Comment: i did some blogs posts (long ago) on javascript and rails asset pipeline that might be worth taking a look at: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2011/05/29/rails-31-javascript-execution/ AND http://jessehouse.com/blog/2011/05/26/rails-31-asset-pipeline/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in `app/assets/javascripts/some_file.js`

If you haven't modified your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file, rails should pick it up next time you start your server.